# Form input (phone number) to email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I know this is quite basic, but I wonder if someone is willing to help me or guide me with this. So, I am looking to have my visitors input a phone number which is then submitted to my email after pressing submit. It should only be submitted once, and when pressing the submit button the form should dissappear and a thank you message should appear. How can I do this. This is what I've managed (with limited knowledge) to do so far:

php:

```
<?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
mail("example@example.com", "Form to email message", $_POST["message"],    
"From: example@example.com");
}
?>
```

html:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
```

If I change example@example.com to my email I receive an email with the input. How can I make the form dissappear after submitting and display a thank you message and also make the browser not send the form again every time the visitor refresh the page?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: After sending mail send him to another page Like thank-u page. you can do it by header('location:thank-u page.php'). If you want to show him message then send message alogn with it

Comment: Thanks anant kumar singh. The thing is that I'm using bootstrap and I am putting the form within an alert-dismissible div at the top of my page and would like the form to dissappear and the message to display within that alert to save some space and make it more user friendly by not redirecting  the user to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple approach would be:

```
<?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
mail("example@example.com", "Form to email message", $_POST["message"],    
"From: example@example.com");
echo 'THANKS!';

}else{
echo '<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit">';
}

?>
```